# GiveRecognitionBadge user permission

Tags: permissions, ant

I am getting `Unknown user permission: GiveRecognitionBadge` while deploying the admin profile by `ANT`.I can  the comment the permission in the profile XML and deploy but it would be great to know what this permission is so that i can do the necessary in the target org to get rid of this error and save some time.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the sandbox you're deploying from is already on Winter '19 (v.44), but your production org is on Summer '18 (v.43).  The GiveRecognitionBadge permission is related to the new "Give Badge" functionality detailed in the release notes here:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_networks_give_badge_button.htm

Comment: You are right  the api version of the source org is 44 while the destination is 43.Both the source and destination are sandboxes.I guess nothing can be done other than waiting

Comment: Aside from manually removing it from your package.xml file, I think you're right.  We use Gearset for CI/CD and we've done the equivalent to exclude things like this in the past.  Sorry I couldn't give you better news!

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue, thanks for the link.

I did use Workbench to retrieve, and both in Workbench, and in the Package.xml, I specified version 43, so it should not have shown up.
Will just clean up manually for now.